# How to add a pop up as input type for bundle items selection?

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product, input

I want to display options for bundle items on a pop up, along with the link of the product details page of the products that are being displayed as options.
So as soon as the user clicks on a button, a pop up opens which contains all the options for that particular product. The user should be able to select one of those and then the pop up closes.
Can that be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly your problem is, but this sounds like you want to add a `display:none` to the block with the options, then have a call to action somewhere, like a button or link to show the block again.

Then you have the show/hide logic.

To position it you want something like:

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```